# How to install njs on nginx for Windows

Tags: windows, nginx

We are running [nginx for Windows](https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) and are trying to [validate OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens](https://www.nginx.com/blog/validating-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-nginx/).
This requires installing [njs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html), however, the only options for [installing](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/install.html) are

- Installing as a Linux package
- Building from the sources

How does one go about installing njs on nginx for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Spending some time and digging into this, I think I can answer this question. The answer is "No, njs is incompatible with the non-POSIX platforms and cannot be built on those platforms".

Windows doesn't listed in the [Tested OS and platforms](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/#tested_os_and_platforms) documentation chapter, and the [following](https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/320#issuecomment-645199347) GitHub comment states this explicitly.

However you can achieve the same functionality on Windows using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) or [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) bundle which **are** available on Windows platform. The subrequests API similar to `auth_request` used by the example you are referring on can be used via [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture), and the whole example can be easily rewritten using the LUA language.

Comment: Where do you read that lua can be used on Windows or rather: how does one install modules on NGINX Free for Windows?